# Fix an overlapping html header Javascript bug?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok I was trying to implement a header that resizes upon scrolling, BUT I also added another solution to it called [Headroom](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/), I got it to work just fine as far as the header hiding. You can see the my progess [HERE.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wevLo) If you would notice the first time you do it, you see no glitch, it smoothly resizes to the smaller header of 45px, and then headroom activates and hides the header. BUT the second or any other time after, it doesn't Smoothly resize, but rather it glitches, or JUMPS into the smaller header and then headroom activates, I am trying to get it where it always smoothly resizes when you scroll (you will see that it goes smaller at( shrinkOn = 50) and then hides itself with headroom(you'll see in the headroom code that the tolerance is 300)

This is script that shrinks header

```
<script>
      function init() {
          window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
             var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                  shrinkOn = 50,
                  header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY       
                       > shrinkOn)
  {                                                                                                                                                                                     
            classie.add(header,"smaller", "headroom");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller", "headroom")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller", "headroom");
            }
        }
    });
}
      window.onload = init();
  </script>
```

This is Script that Activates Headroom

```
  var myElement = document.querySelector("header");
  // construct an instance of Headroom, passing the element
  var headroom  = new Headroom(myElement);
  // initialise
  headroom.init();
```

These are the options

```
  "tolerance": 2,
  "offset": 350,
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, when you start off, your classes on the header are: `headroom headroom--top`

As you go through the transitions, you add `smaller`, and remove `headroom--top`, replacing with `headroom--not-top` and adding `headroom--unpinned`. So second bar:

```
headroom smaller headroom--top headroom--pinned
```

And ending at:

```
headroom smaller headroom--not-top headroom--unpinned
```

Then, going back up through the transitions, you switch `headroom--not-top` with `headroom--top` and `headroom--unpinned` with `headroom--pinned`, and then remove `smaller`, but never remove `headroom--pinned`, which is what you'd need to do to get back to your initial state.

So, the upshot here is to add this line in the script:

```
...snip
    classie.remove(header,"smaller", "headroom");
    classie.remove(header,"headroom--pinned", "headroom");  //add this line here
}
```

Take a look here:
[Your forked codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hEyar)

Comment: Awesome! that's right, never thought about it never being unpinned, Thank you, Exactly what I was looking for!